# How can `npm install` fail with dependency conflicts, but `npm clean-install` works?

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

This week I cloned a certain project for the first time; no `node_modules` folder, `package.json` and `package-lock.json` files where I expect them to be.

When I ran `npm install`, I got a host of "ERSOLVE: unable to resolve dependency tree" errors. So on the advice of the internet, I deleted `node_modules` and `package-lock.json` and tried again: same result.

Then I deleted `node_modules`, restored `package-lock.json` from git, and tried something new (for me): `npm clean-install` - and wouldn't you know it, this worked perfectly. All installs complete without error.

The problem is now I can't install new packages; any call to `npm install [package]` fails on the same conflicts as when I started. Evidently, `package.json` has some explicitly incompatible specs in it. (I have started trying to resolve these by hand, but every change breeds new conflicts).

So I have two questions here:

First, for my curiosity: how does this happen? I was under the impression that `npm install [package]` would a) update `package.json` with compatible semver specs and b) simultaneously record a precise version in `package-lock.json` -- how can I have incompatible semver values in `package.json` like this?

Second, much more importantly: what is the correct way to resolve this? I cannot find a "good" version of `package.json` so far, but I do have a totally valid `package-lock.json` -- is there any way to automatically pull compatible version numbers/semver values from there?

**EDIT:** The rogue files:

**package.json**

https://gist.github.com/RZABob/c368712d13caf15c43f29001d8d53956

**package-lock**

https://gist.github.com/RZABob/2af12efc536c98940c14858f4f6a4685

Comment: Can you share the package and package-lock files?

Comment: I would but package-lock.json is 25k lines...

Comment: You can upload it to pastebin or github gists or another similar service, then share the link to that

Comment: I had a similar problem, and I fixed it by downgrading to NPM 7.7.6 and Node 15.14.0. I have no clue why this worked for me.

Comment: That may have been my workaround, too, I don't remember now. Mainly I'm confused by how it can get stuck THIS way, it seems contrary to how these methods work.